# What is the recommended way to update a proc entry from Python

Tags: python, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a linux proc entry in `/proc/sys/fs/offs/ts/enable` which toggles a flag in a custom kernel module.  Setting the value to 1 will enable a mode in the module, setting to 0 will disable that mode.

In bash, to enable the mode, I would simply do

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/fs/offs/ts/enable
```

And to disable it,

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/fs/offs/ts/enable
```

I have a daemon written in Python 2.7 which will look for some external event trigger, and when that event fires, should enable or disable the feature in the kernel module.  The daemon is run with root privileges, so I shouldn't run into any kind of permissions issues.

Is there a recommended way of setting this value from python?

For example, say my function right now looks like this.

```
def set_mode(enable=True):
    with open('/proc/sys/fs/offs/ts/enable', 'w') as p:
        if enable:
            p.write("1")
        else:
            p.write("0")
        p.flush()
```

Comment: I would make two functions out of this: `def enable(): ...` and `def disable(): ...`

Comment: @JonasGröger I do agree that this should be 2 functions, but that's not really the point of the question.  The code block was a simple example showing what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Thats why this is a comment and not an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

Firstly, you want to write to the file, but you're opening it in read mode.

Secondly, `.write` expects string data, not an integer.

We can get rid of the `if` test by exploiting the fact that `False` and `True` have integer values of 0 & 1, respectively. The code below uses the `print` function rather than `.write` because `print` can convert the integer returned by `int(enable)` to a string. Also, `print` appends a newline (unless you tell it not to via the `end` argument), so this way the Python code performs the same action as your Bash command lines.

```
def set_mode(enable=True):
    with open('/proc/sys/fs/offs/ts/enable', 'w') as p:
        print(int(enable), file=p)
```

If you want to do it with `.write`, change the `print` line to:

```
p.write(str(int(enable)) + '\n')
```

There's a way to do that conversion from boolean to string in one step: use the boolean to index into a string literal:

```
'01'[enable]
```

It's short & fast, but some would argue that it's a little cryptic to use booleans as indices.

Answer (score 1):

Linux exposes the /proc filesystem, as the name says, as *files*. That means you'll operate on those files like you would do with any other file. Your suggested function is basically perfect regarding how to access /proc, but [PM 2Ring's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40680189/171318) recommendations are definitely valid.

Answer (score -1):

Since it is a low level code, not intended to be portable, I would use `os` module. It has functions `open`, `write` and `close` that are almost direct wrappers of the C counterparts.

More like C equals less surprises!

Comment: I don't agree. The documentation clearly states: **Do not import this module directly.**

Comment: @JonasGröger: Oh, ok. The recommendation is to use `os` that has the same functions. Updated.

Comment: I still don't see why you would do that

Comment: @hek2mgl: Because the OP is interacting with a kernel module. Every system call is possibly seen from the kernel module, so the thinner the python wrapper is, the better. Using `builtins.open()` you don't know how many system calls there are, or what are exactly the parameters used, but using `os.open()` you do know that.

Comment: A file in /proc is a file. That's it. Either you recommend to always do that when working with files in Python or it doesn't make sense here since a file in /proc is just a file. Further note that if you are working with files on Linux you'll always communicate with a kernel module. That's not something special. There are a few userland filesystem implementations but even those rely on the kernel. The common filesystems on Linux like ext, btrfs are all implemented as kernel modules.

Comment: Part of my concern, which is what makes this answer relevant, is that some files in /proc behave differently, than other files on the system.  For example,  If you try to stat some of the files in /proc they will return 0 size, even though cat'ing the file will show output.  When I asked the question, I wasn't sure if using the builtin `open` call would try to do something like `stat` the file prior to opening the file handle.  In that case, if it did, it may not have worked properly, since `stat` will not function as expected.

Comment: @AnthonyOteri: That is precisely my rationale. Even if today it works properly, future Python versions may add optimizations that break weird files like those (ie. if the file is less than X bytes, load it wholly into memory at open time). That will not happen with functions from `os`.